# как узнать процент потребления процессора процессом через pid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu

Мне требуется узнать процент потребления процессора процессом через pid

Когда я использую этот код:

```py
import psutil

while 1:
    p = psutil.Process(process_pid)
    print(p.cpu_percent(1))
```

Я получаю либо 0 либо завышенные цифры

То-есть если в диспетчере задач у меня у процесса потребление 0.4
то этот код возвращает либо 0 либо около 1.5 процентов

Требуется чтобы код возвращял такие-же значения как и в диспетчере задач

Comment: Возможно это похоже на вашу проблему - https://bit.ly/3inPf8X?

Comment: @Proksima Нет это не это
Я же написал что psutil неправильно определяет потребление